# Rails Routes issue on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

My app working fine on localhost but when I push app on heroku, its show error on heroku. Heroku log  below

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/forgot_password"):

and below is rake routes result
My app working fine on localhost but when I push app on heroku, its show error on heroku log below

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/forgot_password"):

Comment: please paste your rake routes!

Comment: api_v1_forgot_password POST   /api/v1/forgot_password(.:format)                                       api/v1/sessions#forgot_password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your routes suggest the path as "/api/v1/forgot_password". And you are getting the path error as "/forgot_password".

Check the form where you are routing to this path.

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot add routes.rb file with your commit. you need to push that file on heroku